# Issue with Copying and Pasting Files Using Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm encountering an issue when trying to use the Google Drive API to copy and paste a file into a specific folder. The copy operation is successful; however, the copied file is pasted back into the source folder instead of being moved to the specified destination folder.

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
// File ID you want to copy.
const folderId = '1g9rSD-file_copied';

// New folder ID that will be the destination of the copy.
const parentFolderId = '1xu6TIz_my_folder_destination';       
const accessToken = "my_access_token_here";

const requestBody = {
    parents: [parentFolderId],
    supportsAllDrives: true,
};

const queryString = new URLSearchParams(requestBody).toString();
const copyUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${folderId}/copy?${queryString}`;

fetch(copyUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {

    console.log('Cópia concluída:', data);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Erro na requisição:', error);
});
```

I expected the file to be copied to the folder specified in `parentFolderId`, but instead, it's pasted into the source folder.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or has any suggestions on what might be causing this unexpected behavior?

Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `copy and paste a file into a specific folder`, I thought that you might have copied a file to the specific folder. But, from `// Folder ID you want to copy.` and `const folderId = '1g9rSD-file_copied';`, do you want to copy a folder to the specific folder? I'm confusing for understanding your question. If you want to copy a folder to a specific folder, in the current stage, the folder cannot be directly copied by "Method: files.copy". If I misunderstood your expected result, please tell me.

Comment: I apologize, I really misspoke and caused confusion. I have a folder (model_files) with a file named costs.xls inside. Currently, my hierarchy is: `/model_files/costs.xls.` I'm trying to copy the costs.xls file to another folder called projects. Therefore, the expected result should have the following hierarchy: `/projects/costs.xls`. However, instead, I'm getting this hierarchy: `/model_files/costs(1).xls`. In other words, this code is copying and pasting the file in the same folder, not in the folder specified in parentFolderId. It's simply duplicating and adding (1) to differentiate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy a file `costs.xls` in the folder `model_files` to the folder `model_files`.
- You want to achieve this using the fetch API of Javascript.
- Your access token is a valid token for copying the file using Drive API.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you run this script, please set `fileId`, `destinationFolderId`, and `accessToken`.

```js
// Please set the file ID of the file "costs.xls".
const fileId = '###';

// Please set the folder ID of the folder "model_files".
const destinationFolderId = '###';

// Please set your access token.
const accessToken = "###";


const queryParameters = { supportsAllDrives: true };
const queryString = new URLSearchParams(queryParameters).toString();
const copyUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}/copy?${queryString}`;

fetch(copyUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ parents: [destinationFolderId] })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    console.log('Cópia concluída:', data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Erro na requisição:', error);
  });
```

- When this script is run, the file of `fileId` is copied to the folder of `destinationFolderId`.
- At Google Drive, the files and folders are managed by the unique IDs. So, when the file ID is known, the file can be directly retrieved even when the parent folder ID of the file is not known.

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/copy)

Comment: It worked, thank you! Actually, I wanted to copy the file costs.xls from the projects folder to the model_files folder, but I understood your solution and it worked very well. Adding the 'parents' attribute in the body, and not in the URL, was the perfect solution for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Gilvanei Bispo About `It worked, thank you!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Gilvanei Bispo Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.